# Countable and Uncountable Functions

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, elementary-set-theory, infinity

Let $F$ be the set of all functions $f : ${0,1}$ -> \Bbb N$. Prove that $F$ is countable.

Let $G$ be the set of all functions $g$ : $\Bbb N$ -> ${0,1}$. Prove that $G$ is uncountable.

My poor attempt (a):

[image]

The left hand grid shows the elements $ ${0,1}$ \times \Bbb N$ and the right hand grid shows the natural numbers. By taking the max$(a,b)$ where $a \in ${0,1}$ $, $b$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$, there is a bijection from $ ${0,1}$ \times \Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$, namely the function $g$ : $ ${0,1}$ \times \Bbb N$ -> $\Bbb N$. Each natural number appears exactly once in the right hand grid and each pair $ ${0,1}$ \times \Bbb N$ appears exactly once in the left hand grid and maps to exactly one natural number. So countably infinite.

(b) I don't really know. I was thinking of forming an injective function from $\Bbb R$ to $ \Bbb N \times ${0,1}$ $. Any help ?

Comment: Your proof for (a) is not the right one. What you are proving is that the set $\{0,1\}\times\Bbb N$ is countable, but that set is not $F.$ An element  of $F$ is not an ordered pair $(a,b)$ with $a\in\{0,1\}$ and $b\in\Bbb N.$ Choosing some $f\in F$ amounts to choosing $f(0)$ and $f(1)\in\Bbb N,$ i.e. choosing some ordered pair in $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N.$

Comment: As for (b), here is one of the many duplicates: [Prove that the set of all binary sequences is uncountable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546835/prove-that-the-set-of-all-binary-sequences-is-uncountable)

Comment: Duplicate of (a) *and* (b): [Why is the set of all functions mapping $\{0,1\}\to\Bbb N$ countable, but the set of all functions mapping $\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$ uncountable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265092)